# Simple Process Profiling Tool

Tags: linux, profile

I need to profile a linux process and record high water marks for cpu/mem and also ideally produce a usage graph. Are there any simple command line tools to achieve this?

I have looked at top command run in batch mode but the output does not appear to be easily parsable.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at top, htop, atop or glances if you want to stay on shell.
glances is the most advanced one, it has filters (to focus on your process) and exports to create graphs.

If you need to go into a more advanced analysis, take a look a dtrace/dflame.